# How does Android handle SMS for default SMS app when in Doze Mode and priority is set to '10'?

Tags: android, sms, telephony, android-sms

Consider the following scenario:

- an SMS app is registered as the **default** app
- the priority is set to 10 (as in code below)
- the phone enters Doze mode (STATE IDLE)

> intent-filter android:priority="10"

When happens when an SMS is received? 
Will it wake up the phone from Doze mode? Will the message be delivered into the the app?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution?

Comment: That was a project done a long time ago. Sorry, I cannot remember how this case was concluded.